Significance Testing for Classification Problem with different subsets of the original data
as a foreword this is for a school project.
I trained a random forest model on a medium sized data set, which can be categorized into two groups: present at every time, and not present. I want to perform a significance test on the difference between the accuracy between these two groups. My initial thought was to treat this like a Binomial distribution, as each value is either $1$ or $0$ (correct or incorrect), and then do a P-value test.
However, I think this may be an oversimplification, as there is no reason to think that each observation has the same probability of being correct, and I was wondering if there were normal practices/suggestions for this type of significance testing?
This is the table of my data at the end if it helps anyone:



Group
Accuracy
n




Not Temporary
0.8050
3082


Temporary
0.7855
2555



